# Create a Computed Persisted Column in SQL Server to be used as Primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two columns as below :

```
[logTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[wDate]  AS (CONVERT([date],isnull([logtime],'2012-01-01'),0)) PERSISTED,
```

I'm trying to change the computed wDate column formula to hold the date part of logtime and be able to use it as an index. the column should be persisted.

If I use:

```
ISNULL(Convert(date,logtime,0),Convert(date,'2012-01-01',0))
```

I get the error that the column cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

If I use

```
CONVERT([date],isnull([logtime],'2012-01-01'),0)
```

I cannot clear the Allow Nulls check box to use it in primary Index.

any suggestions on this?

Comment: `logtime` doesn't allow nulls - why are you wrapping it with an `ISNULL` at all?

Comment: It does not allow nulls but SQL Server will not allow me to uncheck 'Allow Nulls' for the wDate Column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works (I don't have your complete table definition so I've made one up):

```
create table T (
    [logTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    ID int not null,
    [wDate] AS ISNULL(DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,[logtime]),0),
                      CONVERT(date,'20120101',112)) PERSISTED,
    constraint PK_T PRIMARY KEY (ID,wDate)
)
```

As does this - I did quite a bit of fiddling to try to get it to work:

```
[wDate] AS ISNULL(CONVERT(date,[logtime],112),
                  CONVERT(date,'20120101',112)) PERSISTED
```

This second gets `wDate` as `date` instead of `datetime`, which may be part of what you wanted to achieve. However, the first will never produce a non-midnight time, so overall they're comparable.

---

Finally, Doh!:

```
[wDate] AS CONVERT(date,[logtime],112) PERSISTED,
```

also works.

Comment: The second worked perfectly. But the third solution does not allow clearing allow nulls. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table studentTable (
id int identity(1,1) not null,
--Auto PRIMARY key
student_id AS (RIGHT('S00' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(7)), 7)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY,
student_name varchar(50)
)

-------------------------------------------------------------
insert into studentTable (student_name) values('Test1')
insert into studentTable (student_name) values('Test2')
insert into studentTable (student_name) values('Test3')`
```